# open a SQL database online without using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a database and use it for a Java project on IntelliJ. If I want to run my project on IntelliJ, I need to run my database on MySQL.

I would like to ask whether it would be possible to run my database online without downloading MySQL so that I can run my Java project and work on it when I use my laptop on which isn't MySQL

Comment: If you don't mind small differences in the SQL dialect you could run your entire project using H2, HyperSQL, or Derby. Those database engines reside entirely inside the JDBC drivers. No need to install anything, since the URL specifies the local dir where the data will be stored.

Answer (score 4):

Online mysql might be a security risk. Better option is to use docker image if you don't want to permanently install mysql locally - https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Sorry, I can't comment as I don't have the required reputation. So, adding it as answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You have correctly recognized that I don't want to install MySQL locally. I just need a temporarily solution for my little project :)

Comment: Glad, I could help. Would you be kind to accept this as the answer too.